# Как подключить библиотеку v7-appcompat в Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

Доброго времени суток (увы не у всех оно такое). Скажу сразу в разработке под Андроид совсем зелёный. Мощности моего ПК использовать Android Studio не позволяют без постоянных тормозов (именно поэтому решил попробовать Eclipse). Сразу к сути и обо всём по порядку.

Установлен Eclipse. Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0).
Все SDK tools обновлены до последней версии через SDK Manager.
Установлен Android Support Repositories через SDK Manager.

При создании проекта `File>New>Other...>Android>Android Application Project` выдает ошибки:[image: Неудачное создание проекта]

Теперь касательно первой ошибки, а именно нахождения сборщиком имени стиля `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. Нагуглив я нашёл решение в добавлении к проекту библиотеки `appcompat`. Но как всегда всё пошло наперекосяк и найденные решения не подходили под мою ситуацию, а именно следующие 2 решения.

Решение 1: Скачать Android Support Libraries
Там-то и должны находиться, насколько я понял, полезные библиотеки в т.ч. `appcompat`. Но у меня в SDK Manager'е отсутствует данный пакет в Extras.[image: Отсутствие Android Support Libraries для скачивания]

Решение 2: Подключить библиотеку в проект "вручную"
Для этого необходимо сначала импортировать библиотеку в мой Workspace. `File>Import...>Android>Existing Android Code Into Workspace>`. Нашёл я папку, где лежат эти библиотеки...[image: Библиотеки]

НО! Расширения у файлов библиотек не `.jar`, а `.aar`, из-за чего я стал ещё больше озадачен.[image: Библиотеки с расширением .aar]

Теперь собственно вопросы которые я хотел бы задать:
1) Нужно ли добыть `.jar` из `.arr`, чтобы успешно импортировать библиотеку? Почему я не могу импортировать какими-то средствами эту `.aar` библиотеку (если Android Studio как-то же с ними работает)?
2) Как нормально решить эту проблему не кривыми ковыряниями вручную?
3) Ах да и вот на офф.сайте установка этих библиотек требует доступ к файлам Gradle в проекте, увы у меня их нету. ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: Три вопроса в одном - перебор. Самый дельный вопрос "Как нормально решить эту проблему не кривыми ковыряниями вручную?" - Установить Android Studio. Лучше пусть лагает, чем ковырять костыли. https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt

Comment: Плагин ADT для эклипса безнадёжно устарел и давно заброшен, поэтому создать в нём современное приложение не выйдет. Есть разработка энтузиастов [плагин `AndMore`](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/andmore), но я уже давно не интересовался его судьбой - попробуйте, может с ним что получится. В `Android Support Libraries`, что в SDK-Manager так же лежит старьё, а свежие библиотеки поддержки можно получить только из Maven-репозитория гугла.

Answer (score -2):

Столкнулся с той же проблемой. Нашел решение путем импорта библиотеки в Eclipse (твое решение 2)
Помогло то, что у меня в архивах завалялся старый SDK с еще установленным support. 
Лови по ссылке, скачивай, импортируй, работай :) 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NCxHqGiB980kQ6CWSxcUHr1jgoNrWFED